# Build issues with Xcode 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios11, xcode9

When i'm building for the Store in Xcode 9 GM am getting the below error

```
CompileC /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/xx\ xx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/xxx\ Mobile.build/Release-iphoneos/xx\ xx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxxx.o xxxx\ Mobile/View/xxxx.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

Comment: Whats the error? The text in your question isn't an error.

Comment: @rmaddy I added the screenshot of the failure

Comment: But that doesn't show why it failed. Look at the Build output in Xcode for much greater detail.

Comment: And don't add text as image.

Comment: Solution - I had both xcode 8.3.3 and xcode 9 GM which caused this issue. After deleting the xcode 8.3.3 and moving the xcode 9 to the applications folder the issue was resolved

Comment: Do we have solution, I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always **clean** project and then **build** when you switch/open project between 2 major versions of Xcode (in this case you switched to Xcode 9 from Xcode 8.3.3).